# SQLite DB locking on Windows like a mutex and without polling

Tags: windows, sqlite, transactions, locking, file-locking

I have the following situation:
One process is reading from a SQLite database.
Another processes is updating the database. Updates do not happen very often and all transactions are short. (less than 0.1ms on average)
The process that is reading should have low latencies for the queries. (around 0.1ms)

If the locking of SQLite would work like a mutex or readers-writer lock, everything would be ok.
From reading http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html this should be possible. SQLite is using
LockFileEx(), sometimes without the LOCKFILE_FAIL_IMMEDIATELY, which would block the calling
process as desired.

However I could not figure out how to use/configure SQLite to achieve this behavior. Using a busy-handler
would involve polling, what is not acceptable because the minimal sleep time is usually 15ms on Windows.
I would like that the query is executed as soon as the update transaction ends.

Is this possible without changing the source code of SQLite. If not, is there such a patch available somewhere?

Comment: Looking to the sourcecode again, I found that all LockFileEx are called with LOCKFILE_FAIL_IMMEDIATELY. There is no waiting.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not use a synchronization mechanism that would wait just until a lock is released.
SQLite never uses a blocking locking call; when it finds that the database is locked, is waits for some time and tries again.
(You could install your own [busy handler](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_handler.html) to wait for a shorter time.)

The easiest way to prevent readers and a writer from blocking each other is to use [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

If you cannot use WAL mode, you can synchronize your transactions by implementing your own synchronization mechanism: use a common [named mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411.aspx) in all processes, and lock it around all your transactions.
(This would reduce concurrency if you had multiple readers.)

Comment: WAL mode will indeed solve the read-while-write problem. However I also have multiple writers (not mentioned in my question) and WAL mode does not solve this issue. It's disappointing that SQLite does not support a better locking mechanism. It would be a good idea to improve this area in future releases especially because WAL mode does not support file on a network share.

Comment: busy handler: This will slow down the accesses by a factor of about 100 in my case. (A Sleep(1) will typically wait for at least one timer interrupt cycle . typically 15ms)

Comment: Using a named mutex or semaphore is not going to be practical in my situation because the writers will be implemented in different (scripting) languages. Not all of them allow you access the Win32 API in a easy way. Handling security (and terminal session) would not be simple too.